Finding the relative position of the molecule in the adsorbate and adsorbent by minimizing the Hamiltonian
I am trying to model an adsorbing process (or more precisely, Heterogeneous catalysis process between solid catalyst and gas reactants). One of the step is to minimize the Hamiltonian by optimizing the coordinates of the adsorbent and adsorbate.
To minimize the needs of computing, I define an active space by selecting the electrons and orbitals.
My question is do I need to taking into account of the active electrons / orbitals of the catalyst?

What tools and methods are you using for this calculation? This is far too vague, I can potentially help but I need a lot more context.

@MinhTriet  Are you aware of the sibling site mattermodelling.se and their tag dedicated to adsorption, e.g. Adsorption of naphthalene on graphene oxide sheets with gmx with GROMACS?
